# Unexpected prediction values, tflearn

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Using tflearn, I'm trying to classify images.

My code is

```
import tflearn
dataset_file = 'my_dataset.txt'

X, Y = tflearn.data_utils.image_preloader(dataset_file, image_shape=(128, 128),categorical_labels=True, mode='file', grayscale=True,  normalize=True)

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=(128,128))
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='linear')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=3)
model.fit(X, Y)

print(model.predict(X))
```

Dataset file is as follows:

```
1.jpg 1
2.jpg 1
3.jpg 1
4.jpg 1
5.jpg 0
6.jpg 0
7.jpg 0
```

...where 1 and 0 are classes of images.

My predictions are not what I'd expect, though:

```
[[2.9711711406707764, -3.049826145172119], [9.435855865478516, -11.466367721557617], [-3.7774205207824707, -4.090094089508057], [-7.006657600402832, -3.4418578147888184], [-18.654706954956055, -0.9354709982872009], [-17.237045288085938, -3.1278553009033203], [-18.066274642944336, -1.6454157829284668]]
```

I'm expecting to see a match for image type 1 or 0.
Just a beginner in tflearn, not sure what to do.

Comment: In `tflearn.regression` have you tried setting `to_one_hot=True, n_classes=2`?

Comment: this gives me ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (7, 2) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?,)'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `fully_connected` layer to use `'softmax'` activation

```
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
```

Now, you should be getting outputs of the form:

```
predictions = [[0.999962568283081, 3.739727253559977e-05],
               [0.999962568283081, 3.739727253559977e-05],
               ...]
```

Here `predictions[i][j]` is the probability that the `ith` element in the test set has class `j`. You will notice for all `i`'s `sum(predictions[i]) == 1.0`

Comment: Sum of predictions[i] can't be 1, since first 2 i's are approximately 0.999.

Comment: `sum([0.999962568283081, 3.739727253559977e-05]) ~ 1.0` is what I meant. `predictions[i]` is the list of probabilities for each class.